# Best way to store multiple lines of data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, arrays, plaintext, formatted-text

I'm looking at storing multiple lines of data in MySQL (or your choice), an example would be a poem. I wouldn't know how many lines it could be and I have to keep its structure intact so when I go display it to my end users on a site it is properly formatted.

I could be storing anywhere between 100 characters to 100,000. I'd rather shy from using plain text unless someone can help me figure out an easier method.

Comment: Why would plain text be so bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store the text in a simple format like [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) then you can render it as HTML using any number of libraries that convert.

There's nothing wrong with storing large amounts of text in MySQL. For data over 1KB you should be using `TEXT` for up to 64KB or `LONG TEXT` for much larger amounts.

`VARCHAR` can go to longer lengths under newer versions of MySQL but it's probably not what you intend here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really worried about the formatting. You could also use a content editor that creates html code like `<br/>` and lists for formatting. Then post that into your sql as a text.

Again, I'm not sure exactly if your worried about inputting data into mysql, or worried about displaying it from mysql (Hence, the content editor idea).

Comment: Tho in a not so perfect world, you should be careful of XSS, if allowing html tobe added to posts.

Comment: Well I'll be implementing most of the text myself so I'll know what goes in for quality control. Would it be wise to store it all in MySQL? What would I store it under? VARCHAR is out of the question based off its 255 size restriction.

Comment: People often store full html documents in sql for the ability to have full db driven content. There is pros and cons to this. It's wise because of how quickly you can modify the data. and Like John said above, storing as text is fine, but be sure to understand sql injection attacks for the future. :) @Matthew